# Dynamic If Statement in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler and there's this syntax.

```cs
wt.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday;
```

The problem is I have a list of days

```cs
List<String> days = {"Tuesday", "Thursday"}
```

And I want to turn the list to 'an if statement' dynamically so the result is

```cs
wt.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday | DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday;
```

So far, I think about to loop the list, concat the string, and eval it (even though the eval function doesn't exist natively in C#).

How do I possibly achieve that? Thank you?

Comment: Convert each string to the enum value using `Enum.Parse` and or them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        List<String> days = new List<string> {"Tuesday", "Thursday"};

        DaysOfTheWeek? dow = null;

foreach (var day in days) {
        DaysOfTheWeek dayValue;
         if (Enum.TryParse(day, true, out dayValue)) {
             dow = dow == null ? dayValue : dow | dayValue;
         }
}
```